# F6 Key not working

Tags: keyboard, desktop-computer

I have an issue with just F6 on my Keyboard, Alt F6, Control F6 and Shift F6 all work completely fine. Its just F6 Does not work

Also when I have the on screen keyboard and manually click F6 it is also not working

I have also tried plugging in a second keyboard and the same issue occurs, does anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Based on your question, it is an operating system issue. Assuming Windows, run DISM / SFC:    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Check BIOS settings.